# How to debug Google Analytics when it it only works on my HTTPS site?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, tracking, debug

I have two websites that I would like to monitor and have created to google accounts for them:

- `https://secure.example.com.au` (secure sub-domains only)
- `http://*.example.com.au` (all domains including sub-domains)

After I created the accounts and added the javascript codes, they don't appear to working on `http://*.example.com.au`.

- Is there anything that would cause only the secure variant to work?
- Or is it simple the javascript code I added isn't valid?

One account is configured with the following configuration:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-2XXXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '.example.com.au']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

One account is configured as follows:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-5XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Also is there a way I can test that the codes are working? If I'm getting real-time data, it should work right?

Comment: Which account is working?  You have used ga.js (classic analytics) in the first setup, and analytics.js (universal analytics - newer and better) in your second setup.  I would recommend using universal analytics for all new setups.

Comment: Hmmm, I mixed the classic with newer codes. I think that might be the issue. I'll see if I can generate newer codes for both of them and see if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome Extension called [GA Debug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) which is useful for seeing what tags are being fired on your website.  Install that extension, right click the page and 'Inspect element', go to the 'console' tab and then navigate to the pages you are interested in.  If your tags are firing, they'll appear in the output below.

As I mentioned in the comment, convert your Google Analytics properties to Universal Analytics and begin using universal analytics tags (analytics.js).

It isn't necessary to have different accounts for your secure and non-secure pages, just put the same javascript tag on all pages (unless you really want to keep them separate...).

Comment: I've changed the codes to use the Universal codes on both and both are picking up data. However, the secure website appears to be not to pick up data for the PPC campaigns. In our adword account, we have one campaign that points to the secure sub-domain and another campaign to the normal website.

Comment: Have you linked the Adwords accounts to your GA account? Go into GA admin, go to your Property settings and then the Adwords Linking section.  Make sure all your Adwords are linked.  Then make sure that you have 'auto-tagging' turned on in Adwords.  Also if you have new questions you should ask them in a new question rather than using comments.

Comment: It turned out to be invalid links on the ads.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the GA Debug Chrome Extension, there is another extension by Google called [Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk).

This will check your installation of the GA code on your page and will let you know if there are any issues or errors with the current tag.